# How to get the prop of another component

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-component

I am new to React and I have Googled around but can't figure out how to do what I want to do.

I would like to style a header link differently based on what page I am on. I am wondering how (or if it is possible) to get the prop of another component.

My code so far:

```
class Header extends React.Component {

    getClass() {
        console.log(this.props.currentPage) // Prints the correct value
        let headerType = "h2";
        if (this.props.currentPage === /*Prop of current Link*/){
            headerType = "h1"
        }
        return ("header-links " + headerType);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Link to="/" page_name="Home" className={this.getClass()}>Home</Link>
            <Link to="/About" page_name="About" className={this.getClass()}>About</Link>
            <Link to="/Other" page_name="Other" className={this.getClass()}>Other</Link>               
        );
    }
}
```

Is there some way to get the `page_name` of the `Link` that is calling `getClass()`?

I know I could just pass the name of the page into `getClass()`:

```
<Link to="/" className={this.getClass("Home")}>Home</Link>
```

But I figure there must be a better way.

I'm sure I could get it using vanilla JavaScript (and maybe that is what I should be doing)... but I would like to know if there is a way to accomplish this with `Link`'s props or something similar.

**UPDATE**
My `Route`'s

```
<Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
<Route exact path='/About' component={About}/>
<Route exact path='/Other' component={Other}/>
```

I also noticed I had *Resume* as the `to` prop in the About `Link` by accident, fixed now.

Comment: Can you post your Route's?

Comment: Hi Zac, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea you already have of passing static name will also work,

```
<Link to="/" className={this.getClass("Home")}>Home</Link>
```

Or you can simplify this, (I advise to use this)

```
<Link to="/" className={"header-links " + (this.props.currentPage === "Home" ? "h1" : "h2")}>Home</Link>
<Link to="/About" className={"header-links " + (this.props.currentPage === "About" ? "h1" : "h2")}>About</Link>
<Link to="/Other" className={"header-links " + (this.props.currentPage === "Other" ? "h1" : "h2")}>Other</Link>
```

Or another way is passing `props` in `Route's`,

```
<Route exact path='/' component={() => <Home page_name="Home" />}/>
<Route exact path='/About' component={() => <About page_name="About" />}/>
<Route exact path='/Other' component={() => <Other page_name="Other" />}/>
```

Now in your `Header` component you can do this,

```
getClass() {
   console.log(this.props.currentPage) // Prints the correct value
   let headerType = "h2";
   if (this.props.currentPage === this.props.page_name){ //get page_name passed from Route's
       headerType = "h1"
   }
   return ("header-links " + headerType);
}
```

By passing `props` in `Route's`, you need to do `prop-drilling`.

```
<Header currentPage="Home" page_name={this.props.page_name} />  //Also need to do for other components
```

**Note:** `prop-drilling` is expensive and not advisable.

Comment: This is great, if you could explain how the prop-drilling code works (because it seems very strange to me, but is what I was looking for) as well as why it is not advisable, I will mark your answer as correct!

Comment: `prop-drilling` is the concept of passing down the props to child component. As your `header` is child and `Home`, `About` are parent you need to pass the props down to access the props in `header` (child) component.

Comment: `prop-drilling` is expensive, because consider you have a child of `Header` and want to access the props in that component, in that case you again need to pass down the props to that child component and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Well if you're trying to get the props of another component in React, you can use a state management tool like Redux(not necessary here) or put the component in a parent component. 
 `<ParentComponent props={this.state.links} /> //passes down links as a prop for example`

     and then you can go access links as a prop in your child component like `this.props.links`. I would suggest watch some tutorials on passing down props if you're not sure how it works.

Comment: Thanks, Yousuf. Could expand (with an example preferably) on what you mean by "put the component in a parent component".

Comment: So let's say I have a component called Home. In this component, I have the following as my state... this.state ={ name: " "} . Not let's say I have another component called Profile and I wanted the name variable to also be available in Profile.  I would create Profile and then import it into Home. At the top of Home import Profile like this: import Profile from "../Profile/Profile.js"(or whatever the path is). Display Profile in Home where you want it like this <Profile props={this.state.name} />. You can now access the name variable in Profile through this.props.name

Answer (score 0):

I think you're essentially going about it in a feasible way, although I think you could avoid the need for that by using ternary operators and mapping over an array of your nav link values.

Something like this:

```js
const myLinks = [
  { name: "Home", to: "/" },
  { name: "About", to: "/Resume" },
  { name: "Other", to: "/Other" },
];

const Header = props => (
  <div>
    {myLinks.map((item, i) => (
      <Link
        to={item.to}
        page_name={item.name}
        className={`header-links ${
          props.currentPage === item.name ? " h1" : " h2"
        }`}
      >
        {item.name}
      </Link>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

Edit: This is assuming a prop called `currentPage` is being passed into your header component, of course!

Comment: Thanks, StoutLabs, I know that I can map over all of the links and use a condition to determine the class but I am specifically looking for a way to get a prop from a component inside the current context's component. See ravibagul91's answer.